# issue, how Fix get JSON from URL in android?, Onclicklistener? AsyncTask? OnPostExecute?

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, getjson

/////////////////////////////FIRST TRY, first attempt:////////////////////////

hi guys is my first time making an android application, and is only a test to see if it works, so my problem is this:
  I made an application in iOS that sending someones parameters to a URL that me returns a Json String value, only a value chain, my iOS code is:

```
 URL = [[self replaceRealURL:[self GetUrlForRegisterWithName:NameValue Mail:MailValue Language:Language Country:Country]]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *Filtro = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];

    NSLog(@"%@",URL);


    dispatch_async(HILO_REGISTRO, ^{

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:Filtro];

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
        //[self fetchedData:data];
    });

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

NSError* error;

NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization

                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                      options:kNilOptions

                      error:&error];


NSString *CodigoDeError = [json objectForKey:@"error"];

if ([CodigoDeError isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    // Existe
    NSLog(@"%@",json);
    [progressUpload hide:YES];
    UIAlertView *YaExiste = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Usuario registrado"
                                                       message:@"Este usuario ya ha sido registrado"
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [YaExiste show];
}
else if ([CodigoDeError isEqualToString:@"2"])
{
    // Argumentos Invalidos
    NSLog(@"%@",json);
    [progressUpload hide:YES];
    UIAlertView *NoValidos = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Su email no es válido"
                                                        message:@"Por favor ingrese un email válido"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [NoValidos show];
}    }
-(NSString*)GetUrlForRegisterWithName:(NSString*)name Mail:(NSString*)mail Language:(NSString*)language Country:(NSString*)country
{
NSString *PushToURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://MIPAGINA.com/PRUEBA/regiphone/?name=%@&email=%@&lang=%@&country=%@",name,mail,language,country];
return PushToURL;
 }
```

and it works perfectly, but in Android I am using this code in my activity:

```
textNombre = URLEncoder.encode(textNombre,"utf-8");
                    textMail = URLEncoder.encode(textMail,"utf-8");
                    Idioma = URLEncoder.encode(Idioma,"utf-8");
                    Pais = URLEncoder.encode(Pais,"utf-8");


                    JSONUrl = "http://MIPAGINA.com/PRUEBA/regiphone/?name="+textNombre+"&email="+textMail+"&lang="+Idioma+"&country="+Pais;

                /*  Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                             JSONUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            msg.show();*/
                    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                    // getting JSON string from URL
                    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONUrl);

                    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                             JSONUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            msg.show();

                            try {


                                String CodigoDeError = jsonobject.getString("error");

                                if(CodigoDeError.equals("1"))
                                {
                                    String Mensaje = "Este usuario ya ha sido registrado";
                                    Toast msge = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                             Mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                            msge.show();
                                }
                                else if (CodigoDeError.equals("2")) 
                                {
                                    String Mensaje = "Por favor ingrese un email válido";
                                    Toast msge = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                             Mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                            msge.show();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    CodigoDeError = jsonobject.getString("id");
                                    String NSLOG = "Nslog";
                                    Log.i(NSLOG, CodigoDeError.toString());
                                    String Mensaje = "Muchas gracias por registrarse";
                                    Toast msge = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                             Mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                            msge.show();
                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

I dont know if I'm doing something wrong or should receive json from url I did create, the code for both run in Ibaction and in a OnClickListener, but what is wrong? the app crash and show:

[image]

And the Logcat show me this, is for is the URL? from http request?:

[image]

Please any help from a simple Json get from Url? the code for Java Android Eclipse in which I base is in this tutorial form android hive :http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

```
               //------------------------------------------//
               //           THANKS StackOverFlow           //
               //          GRETTINGS FROM BOLIVIA          //
               //             ROCK ON!!!! n_n'             //
               //------------------------------------------//
```

/////////////////////////////          EDIT           ///////////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////SECOND TRY, second attempt:////////////////////////

well someons commrads recommended me using AsyncTask and change my code so and is:

```
  registrarseBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        new Registration().execute();
    }

  class Registration extends AsyncTask<Void,String, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Auto Venta");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Registrando...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            String textNombre;
            String textMail;
            String Idioma;
            String Pais;
            //-------Validando Nombre -----//
             // String textNombre;

              if (nombreTextField.getText().toString().length() <= 0) 
              {
                nombreTextField.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
                textNombre = null;
            } else if (!nombreTextField.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) 
            {
                nombreTextField.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
                textNombre = null;
            } else 
            {
                textNombre=nombreTextField.getText().toString();
            }
              //-------- Validando eMail --------//

              //String textMail;
              if (mailTextField.getText().toString() == null) {
                mailTextField.setError("Invalid Email Address");
                textMail = null;
            } else if (isEmailValid(mailTextField.getText().toString()) == false) {
                mailTextField.setError("Invalid Email Address");
                textMail = null;
            } else {
                textMail = mailTextField.getText().toString();
            }

            //-------Armando Cadena para URL------// 


              Idioma = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
              TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
              Pais = tm.getSimCountryIso();

                        try {

                            textNombre = URLEncoder.encode(textNombre,"utf-8");
                            textMail = URLEncoder.encode(textMail,"utf-8");
                            Idioma = URLEncoder.encode(Idioma,"utf-8");
                            Pais = URLEncoder.encode(Pais,"utf-8");


                            JSONUrl = "http://MIPAGINA.com/PRUEBA/websites/regiphone/?name="+textNombre+"&email="+textMail+"&lang="+Idioma+"&country="+Pais;

                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

             // getting JSON string from URL
             JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONUrl);

             return json;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) 
        {

            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    JSONUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                   msg.show();

                   try {


                       String CodigoDeError = jsonobject.getString("error");

                       if(CodigoDeError.equals("1"))
                       {
                           String Mensaje = "Este usuario ya ha sido registrado";
                           Toast msge = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    Mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                   msge.show();
                       }
                       else if (CodigoDeError.equals("2")) 
                       {
                           String Mensaje = "Por favor ingrese un email válido";
                           Toast msge = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    Mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                   msge.show();
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           CodigoDeError = jsonobject.getString("id");
                           String NSLOG = "Nslog";
                           Log.i(NSLOG, CodigoDeError.toString());
                           String Mensaje = "Muchas gracias por registrarse";
                           Toast msge = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    Mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                   msge.show();
                       }


                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
        }
    }

    boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email)
    {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    } 
     });



}
```

the problem is the same the app crashes and Idont know what is wrong, if I would change something in my code? the logcat show me this?

```
 11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): Process: com.example.prototipo, PID: 1200
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at com.example.prototipo.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:38)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at com.example.prototipo.MainActivity$1$Registration.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:153)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at com.example.prototipo.MainActivity$1$Registration.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     ... 4 more
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     ... 18 more
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-13 09:37:42.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1200):     ... 21 more
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.prototipo.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b4150488 V.E..... R......D 0,0-480,243} that was originally added here
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:346)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at com.example.prototipo.MainActivity$1$Registration.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:89)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at com.example.prototipo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:73)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-13 09:37:45.580: E/WindowManager(1200):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 09:37:46.390: I/Process(1200): Sending signal. PID: 1200 SIG: 9
```

please help!

/////////////////////////////THIRD TRY, third attempt:////////////////////////

Thanks:

```
@popovitsj, @Phil, @printemps, @aegean, @Wang,
```

but I added

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to my manifest.xml file and the app crashes too, and the logcat now show me this:

```
11-13 10:06:03.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1256): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 10:06:03.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1256): Process: com.example.prototipo, PID: 1256
11-13 10:06:03.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1256): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 10:06:03.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at com.example.prototipo.MainActivity$1$Registration.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:167)
11-13 10:06:03.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at com.example.prototipo.MainActivity$1$Registration.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
11-13 10:06:03.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
11-13 10:06:03.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
11-13 10:06:03.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
11-13 10:06:03.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-13 10:06:03.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-13 10:06:03.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-13 10:06:03.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 10:06:03.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-13 10:06:03.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-13 10:06:03.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-13 10:06:03.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1256):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 10:06:06.000: I/Process(1256): Sending signal. PID: 1256 SIG: 9
```

OK The register runs finally,SO, the problem now is in the onPostExecute, the problem is that when I insert the data in the URL, it returns me error code or just an id of the record in JSON like this:

```
{
  error:1
}
```

or

```
{
 id:123
}
```

but in my asyncTask what is wrong???? please help Guys!!!

Comment: Are you doing the request asynchronously?

Comment: not yet, because the proof that I am doing is very simple based on this tutorial :http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Then that's probably the reason it's not working. Modern API versions of Android do not allow network requests on the main thread. Try setting your API to lvl 8 and see if it works now.

Comment: thanks,but I did try but show me the same error, I did edit the question and in the Logcat show this

Comment: That's weird, I thought that should work on lvl 8 and the NetworkOnMainThreadException is exactly what I was expecting. You're just gonna have to do it asynchronously I'm afraid.

Comment: Have a look into [droidQuery](http://bit.ly/droidquery). It has simplified *JSON* getting and parsing methods that will help you out a lot.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?) --> Have you set it?

Comment: SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)

Comment: Thanks popovitsj, Phil, printemps, aegean, Wang, but I edit my question in the third try and the logcat show this O_O???

Answer (score 1):

Logcat should show something. Try to reconnect the device and check if you've selected the correct device in the DDMS perspective.

//EDIT

You're trying to run a network call on the UI thread. Try using an AsyncTask to do a background call. [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Something like this:

```
new AsyncTask<JSONURL, Integer, JSONObject> {
 protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONURL... urls) {
     JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

     // getting JSON string from URL
     JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONUrl);

     return json;
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
     Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                         JSONUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        msg.show();

                        try {


                            String CodigoDeError = jsonobject.getString("error");

                            if(CodigoDeError.equals("1"))
                            {
                                String Mensaje = "Este usuario ya ha sido registrado";
                                Toast msge = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                         Mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                        msge.show();
                            }
                            else if (CodigoDeError.equals("2")) 
                            {
                                String Mensaje = "Por favor ingrese un email válido";
                                Toast msge = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                         Mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                        msge.show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                CodigoDeError = jsonobject.getString("id");
                                String NSLOG = "Nslog";
                                Log.i(NSLOG, CodigoDeError.toString());
                                String Mensaje = "Muchas gracias por registrarse";
                                Toast msge = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                         Mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                        msge.show();
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
        }
 }.execute(JSONURL);
```

This is just an example. There could be some errors in the code.

Comment: how would be the code if I try run this in on click listener? it would be with runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { " here code?? "});, because I did try and I have the same problem like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438016/asynctask-crashes-in-onclicklistener, only I want get the word from json value pushing a simple button in android

Comment: You're trying to manipulate a View object from doInBackground. Move code to onPostExecute and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Wnag I change my code but still I have the same problem, I edit my question and do not know what I did wrong this time

Answer (score 0):

thanks:

```
@popovitsj, @Phil, @printemps, @aegean, @Wang,
```

finally my code finish with:

```
registrarseBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            new Registration().execute();
        }

      class Registration extends AsyncTask<Void,String, JSONObject> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                // Set progressdialog title
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("Auto Venta");
                // Set progressdialog message
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Registrando...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                // Show progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }


            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) 
            {
                String textNombre;
                String textMail;
                String Idioma;
                String Pais;
                //-------Validando Nombre -----//
                 // String textNombre;

                  if (nombreTextField.getText().toString().length() <= 0) 
                  {
                    nombreTextField.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
                    textNombre = null;
                } else if (!nombreTextField.getText().toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) 
                {
                    nombreTextField.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
                    textNombre = null;
                } else 
                {
                    textNombre=nombreTextField.getText().toString();
                }
                  //-------- Validando eMail --------//

                  //String textMail;
                  if (mailTextField.getText().toString() == null) {
                    mailTextField.setError("Invalid Email Address");
                    textMail = null;
                } else if (isEmailValid(mailTextField.getText().toString()) == false) {
                    mailTextField.setError("Invalid Email Address");
                    textMail = null;
                } else {
                    textMail = mailTextField.getText().toString();
                }

                //-------Armando Cadena para URL------// 


                  Idioma = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
                  TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                  Pais = tm.getSimCountryIso();

                            try {

                                textNombre = URLEncoder.encode(textNombre,"utf-8");
                                textMail = URLEncoder.encode(textMail,"utf-8");
                                Idioma = URLEncoder.encode(Idioma,"utf-8");
                                Pais = URLEncoder.encode(Pais,"utf-8");


                                JSONUrl = "http://MIPAGINA.com/PRUEBA/regiphone/?name="+textNombre+"&email="+textMail+"&lang="+Idioma+"&country="+Pais;

                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }

                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                 // getting JSON string from URL
                 JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONUrl);

                 return json;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) 
            {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                       try {

                           String CodigoDeError = json.getString("error");



                           if(CodigoDeError.equals("1"))
                           {
                               String Mensaje = "Este usuario ya ha sido registrado";
                               Toast msge = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                        Mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                       msge.show();
                           }
                           else if (CodigoDeError.equals("2")) 
                           {
                               String Mensaje = "Por favor ingrese un email válido";
                               Toast msge = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                        Mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                       msge.show();
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               CodigoDeError = json.getString("id");
                               String NSLOG = "Nslog";
                               Log.i(NSLOG, CodigoDeError.toString());
                               String Mensaje = "Muchas gracias por registrarse";
                               Toast msge = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                        Mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                       msge.show();
                           }


                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                           Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
            }
        }

        boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email)
        {
            return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
        } 
         });
```

and this is an acceptable answer like the another answers or comments in this question, thanks for your help guys!!